# getElementByID().parentNode is returning null

Tags: javascript

For some reason, this is happening very vaguely. Its working sometimes and sometimes it is not. The same line of code, for the different "myid" under same parent, the line -

`document.getElementById("myid").parentNode` is returning null.

I am quite sure that element "myid" is not a root element and its parent is a DIV which needs to be returned. I am using Firefox 3.6.10 version.

Can anyone suggest any reason why this could be happening?

EDIT: The "myid" here is some kind of a textbox or any other control element. But the parentnode is always DIV. Any controls we add are always wrapped under a DIV. So basically when something on the screen refreshes, we get the parent node and replace the innerhtml. The innerhtml could be anything.

given below is the html I have -

```
<div style="height: 334px; width: 769px; position: relative;">

    <span style="display: inline-block; height: 13px; width: 61px; position: absolute; left: 393px; top: 84px;" bizappid="System856UserGroupAppPoint156d5elabel300" tabindex="-1" id="System856UserGroupAppPoint156d5elabel300">User Group</span>   

    <input type="text" style="height: 20px; width: 221px; position: absolute; left: 503px; top: 77px;" bizappid="System856UserGroupAppPoint156d5etextBox190" class="formtextbox" tabindex="400" id="System856UserGroupAppPoint156d5etextBox190" readonly="readonly" name="System856UserGroupAppPoint156d5etextBox190">
</div>
```

In this Html, assume I am getting ParentNode for Span element, but I am not getting the same parentNode for the Input text element. Also one more strange thing is, I just added a check saying if getelementbyid is not null, then check its parentNode. Then further added if parentNode is not null then do refresh operation. Now the control is not coming inside the parentNode not null condition.

Comment: Is there any change going on that changes the DOM? Can you post some more code, the esp. the HTML?

Comment: Did you do some JavaScript DOM manipulations that could have killed your element or its parent?

Comment: @Nivas - The DOM is getting changed at the "myid" element's children level, but parent is not getting changed. Cannot post any code but have edited my question with more details. Hope it helps you.

Comment: It would help if you would post the code surrounding your `getElementById` call. If `getElementById` really returns a node inside your document, then `parentNode` cannot be null.  Therefore, something else **must** be happening.

Comment: Do a "view source" on the page, copy the rendered code, and post it. No, there is no permission or anything else that would make that fail. I suspect that your "getElementById()" is itself returning null for some reason. Without seeing your actual code it is impossible to say why.

Comment: @Pointy - Real problem is, the view source does not show the actual code. It will only show a control node element which gets replaced by the actual html later. Thats why I cant get to that html. Ok, let me try to get some part of it through debug code or something.

Comment: OK, then use Firebug, or the Chrome developer tools, or the IE8 debugger to look at the code.

Comment: That's good - now what about the **Javascript** code?

Comment: @Pointy - javascript code is just `var obj = document.getElementById("System856UserGroupAppPoint156d5elabel300"); if( obj ) { var parentNode = obj.parentNode; }`

Comment: Is it possible that you use the same "id" value for more than one element? That's not correct, if so. The `getElementById` function is probably returning a node list to you, so there's no parentNode.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the same "id" value is shared by two or more elements on your page, then `getElementById` (may) return a node list instead of a DOM reference. A node list instance has no "parentNode" property.

Do not re-use "id" values for more than one element is the moral of this story.

Comment: You should add some debugging code, or set a breakpoint in a debugger, and figure out what `getElementById()` is returning.

Comment: there were multiple IDs, ironically there was a bug in validation of uniqueIDs while rendering. Thanks buddy.

Answer (score 2):

should it be `document.getElementById("myid").parentNode`?

Comment: I have used document.getElementById("myid") only. Anyway, edited my question.

Comment: I think Cauly is talking about `getElementById` instead of `getElementByID` (function names are cases sentives)

Comment: @romaintaz - It was my typo error. Edited question again. Its Id in small only.